# What could lead to this misbehavior for the expected sample size (ESS)?

Tags: sampling, sample-size, markov-chain-montecarlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I am using Hamiltonian Monte Carlo (HMC) to sample the posterior of a continuous-time Markov Chain (CTMC).

However, after running 10 parallel chains with 100 draws each, the effective sample size (ESS) rises in a certain pattern, way beyond the actual sample size (which should be 10 * 100 = 1000 samples).

[image: plot]

**Has anyone seen this pattern before? What could be the cause of this misbehavior?**

To calculate the ESS I am using the `ess()` function from the Arviz Python package with the parameters left to default (i.e. `method="bulk"`).

The trace plot of one of the chains for this parameter looks like this:

[image: plot2]

I figured the oscillations come from the convexity of my target distribution and the fact that I am using HMC to sample it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not an error - it is possible for the effective sample size to be larger than the actual sample size. This means that your MCMC samples provide *more* information about the parameter, than if you had obtained the same number of independent samples directly from the target (posterior) distribution.

To get some intuition about what this means: Imagine that we are doing a Bayesian analysis of a problem where the true posterior distribution for some parameter, $\theta$, (unbeknownst to us) is a normal distribution with $\mu=172$ and $\sigma=12$. If an omniscient statistician were to estimate the posterior mean, $\mu$, for that parameter by directly drawing $N=100$ samples from the posterior $N(172, 12)$ distribution and taking the average, then the standard error of the mean for that estimate would be:

$$
\textrm{SE} = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}  =  \frac{12}{\sqrt{100}} = 1.2
$$

This means that if the omniscient statistician were to repeat this experiment many times (drawing $100$ random samples from the $N(172,12)$ distribution and each time computing the sample mean), then the resulting values would be distributed around the true value, $\mu=172$, with a standard deviation of approximately $1.2$.

If we instead use MCMC to estimate $\mu$ using $N=100$ iterations (post warmup), and learn that $\textrm{ESS}>N$ then this means that our uncertainty about $\mu$ is *less* than $1.2$: if we were to run the MCMC for 100 iterations multiple times, then the posterior means from each run would be distributed around the true value with a standard deviation that was less than $1.2$.

This can happen when consecutive MCMC samples are negatively correlated: ESS is often defined as:

$$
\textrm{ESS} = \frac{N}{1 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\rho_n}
$$

where $\rho_n$ is the lag-n autocorrelation (i.e., the correlation between the samples and the samples shifted n steps). If there is negative autocorrelation for odd lags then the denominator can be less than 1 leading to the situation where $\textrm{ESS}>N$.

---

Stan reference manual: [Effective Sample Size](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_20/reference-manual/effective-sample-size-section.html)
Andrew Gelman blog: [Simple example of anticorrelated samples](https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/01/18/measuring-speed-stan-incorrectly-faster-thought-cases-due-antithetical-sampling/)
Wikipedia: [Antithetic variates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20antithetic%20variates,to%20obtain%20an%20accurate%20result.)
Aki Vehtari GitHub: [Comparison of MCMC effective sample size estimators](https://avehtari.github.io/rhat_ess/ess_comparison.html)

Comment: Important caveat: ESS is always for a specific quantity (AFAIK arviz defaults to the mean of rank-normalized values, but ESS for mean is also commonly reported). While it is possible to have ESS > N for a _specific_ quantity, you cannot have ESS > N for _all_ quantities at the same time - there's no free lunch, if your MCMC provides more information than i.i.d. samples about the central tendency of a distribution, it has to provide less info for some other aspect (though the other aspects may often be less important to you).